# update column in all rows in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, string, sql-update, concatenation

I have a table called `tbl_portfolio` described as below and i want to modify all `imagePath` columns by adding `projectId` at start, i.e `abc.jpg` will change to `<project_id>/abc.jpg`.I am not very skilled with Mysql.. :(

```
| portfolioId | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| projectId   | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| customerId  | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| imagePath   | varchar(500) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| description | text         | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| addDate     | date         | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| lastUpdated | date         | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| coverPhoto  | int(1)       | YES  |     | 0       |                |
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

Use [**CONCAT**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) function to merge the string

```
UPDATE tbl_portfolio 
SET imagePath = CONCAT(CAST(projectId AS CHAR(20)), '/', imagePath);
```

Answer (score 1):

Please You are use Update Query.

```
<?php
  $Query= UPDATE tbl_portfolio SET imagePath='/abc.jpg' WHERE portfolioId=1;
  mysql_query ($Query);

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE tbl_portfolio
SET imagePath = CONCAT(projectId,"/",imagePath);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this
without where clause its update all rows. read this for more http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat

```
UPDATE tablename 
set imagePath = CONCAT(CAST(projectId AS CHAR(20)),"/",imagePath)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this will help

```
UPDATE tbl_portfolio SET imagePath = CONCAT('/', projectId);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can include column values to another columns value. See simple example:

```
UPDATE tbl_portfolio SET imagePath = tbl_portfolio.projectId + '/' + tbl_portfolio.imagePath;
```

Answer (score -2):

you can use udate table command, the exact syntax will be like -

UPDATE tbl_portfolio SET imagePath='/abc.jpg';

more infoe here - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html